# CIL hex code to call method in another assembly

Tags: cil

For example, I'm writing code in assembly A, and the method I want to call is in assembly B at 0x06000DF2. Here is the hex dnSpy create for me 6F8701000A, but I don't know how it's calculated. Please explain to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first byte (`6F`) indicates that it is the callvirt instruction, the remaining 4 bytes is the metadata token for the method little endian byte order.

```
callvirt 0x0A000187
```

The metadata token is a reference to a particular row in a particular table in the metadata of the current module (the module that contains the IL). The high order byte indicates the type of token (and hence, which metadata table to look in), while the remaining 3 bytes indicates the row number within the table. `0x0A` indicates that the target row is in the `MemberRef` table and the referenced record will provide the details necessary to find the correct member.

The MemberRef table is described in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) Partition II, section 22.25.

Comment: Yes, I know that but you didn't explain how the method token 0x06000DF2 in assembly B is translated into 0x0A000187 when I call that method from assembly A

Comment: "and the referenced record will provide the details necessary to find the correct member". Basically the MemberRef record will provide the member name, signature and another metadata token identifying the scope within which the member is defined (which is resolved in a similar way).

Comment: @LieuLiau In other words the MethodDef token (like 0x06000DF2) in one assembly is irrelevant when referencing the method from another assembly. Instead, the method is referenced using a MemberRef token, which represents the triple (TypeRef, Name, Signature), which is used to describe the referenced method.

Comment: Thanks BrianReichle and @svick, I understand it now. Thank you very much!